# How to get a stacktrace of a transaction timeout in Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: java, timeout, ejb, weblogic, jta

The exception we usually get and log occurs some time after the timeout detection, when the thread tries to use or check on the transaction status (example bellow). That does not revel much about what were taking too long.

I'd like to get the stacktrace at the moment the transaction manager detects the timeout. How can I do that?

One example of the inner exception we get:

```
weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 33 seconds 
BEA1-008AB08D9B8DFE95E711
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwTransactionRolledback(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:200)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwWrappedTransactionRolledback(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:213)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.handleSystemException(BaseEJBManager.java:412)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.setupTxListener(BaseEJBManager.java:334)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.StatelessManager.preInvoke(StatelessManager.java:145)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.preInvoke(BaseRemoteObject.java:229)
```

Comment: Have you turned up your servers logging level to debug in the admin console? Have you increased the JTA timeout? Are you using hibernate or something else that you can look at?

Comment: I increased the log level and saw the timeout but no stacks of the slow thread. About increasing the JTA timeout, I don't see how it helps getting that stacktrace.